# Generic type definition subtype doesn't reflect as such

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection

Given

```
public class Generic<T> {}
public class SubGeneric<T> : Generic<T> {}
```

All the following are false:

```
typeof(Generic<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SubGeneric<>));
typeof(SubGeneric<>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Generic<>));
typeof(SubGeneric<>).BaseType.Equals(typeof(Generic<>));
```

The first makes sense (until concrete they aren't assignable).  But why this behavior on the other two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SubGeneric<T>` inherits `Generic<T>`, not `Generic<>`

Had it inherited `Generic<>`, it wouldn't convey enough information.
Consider the difference between

```
class Wierd<T1, T2> : Generic<T1> { }
```

and

```
class Wierd<T1, T2> : Generic<T2> { }
```

or even

```
class Wierd<T1, T2> : Generic<Wierd<T2, T1>> { }
```

The `BaseType` includes the specific parameterization of the base type.

`typeof(SubGeneric<>).BaseType.GetGenericArguments()` will return an array containing `SubGeneric<>`'s generic type parameter (`<T>`).

---

```
typeof(SubGeneric<>).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Generic<>);
```

should be true.

Comment: So BaseType non-equivalence is clear, thank you.  But the IsSubclassOf falsity still, well, rings false.  Given the relationship of the two GTDs, why wouldn't this show the inheritance semantic between the two?

Comment: @Marc: Look at my example.  `Wierd<T1, T2>` isn't a subclass of `Generic<>`; it's a subclass of `Generic<T1>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think these assertions make no sense until a `T` is given.

`SubGeneric<T>` is a subclass of `Generic<T>` but `SubGeneric<>` and `Generic<>` (without any `T`) aren't classes at all and cannot derive one from each other, or that may mean that any `SubGeneric<U>` could be a subclass of `Generic<V>`, which obviously is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to do with the generic parameter.

`SubGeneric<string>` is not a subclass of `Generic<int>`

So without knowing about the generic parameter, an inference cannot be made.

```
typeof(SubGeneric<int>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Generic<int>));
typeof(SubGeneric<string>).BaseType.Equals(typeof(Generic<string>));
```

should return `true`.